# Cocos2d Box2d contact listener call different method in collided object

Tags: collision-detection, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have the building object, when it collides with another object I want to call some method inside it.
*Building.mm*

```
-(void)printTest
{
    NSLog(@"printTest method work correctly");
}
```

in my ContactListener I'm trying to call it so:
*ContactListener.mm*

```
#import "ContactListener.h"
#import "Building.h"
void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

    Building *buildA = (Building *)bodyA->GetUserData();
    Building *buildB = (Building *)bodyB->GetUserData();
    if (buildB.tag == 1) {
        NSLog(@"tag == 1");
    }
    if (buildA.tag == 2) {
        NSLog(@"tag == 2");
        [buildA printTest];
    }
}
```

**NSLog(@"tag == 2");** work correctly, **but [buildA printTest];** get error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite printTest]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18595f0'

Obviously I'm referring to the wrong object.
How I can get different method and property in contacted objects from contactlistener class?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on my own.

When I create the body, I forgot to set the `UserData` correctly.

```
body->SetUserData(self);
```

Adding the line above (in `Building.mm`) solved the problem.